# Using FFmpeg to encode 2pass mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use FFmpeg to encode my 4K mp4 file to a 2pass 265 mp4 file for the purposes of testing. I am new to video compression and hope I'm making a simple mistake that someone can correct.

All infos in command line as below:

```html
C:\Ying\FF>C:\Ying\FF\ffmpeg.exe -y -i C:\Ying\FF\Xman-4K_50sec_3840x2160.mp4 -preset veryslow -x265-params pass=1 -vcodec hevc -b:v 15M -acodec libvo
_aacenc -b:a 128K C:\Ying\FF\Xman-4K_3840x2160_50sec_15M_H265_veryslow_2pass.mp4
ffmpeg version N-74286-ge5774f2 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontco
nfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-l
ibfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-am
rwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-lib
twolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --en
able-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 30.100 / 54. 30.100
  libavcodec     56. 57.100 / 56. 57.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 32.100 /  5. 32.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Ying\FF\Xman-4K_50sec_3840x2160.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : X-MEN__DAYS_OF_FUTURE_PAST.Title800
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:50.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11067 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 50.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : (26)01:17:27:726
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 11492 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (de
fault)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 1.7
x265 [info]: build info [Windows][GCC 4.9.2][64 bit] 8bpp
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-5 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 32 threads
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 8 / wpp(34 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 3 inter / 3 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : dia / 57 / 2 / 1
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut       : 25 / 250 / 40
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 40 / 8 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb / refs: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 1 / 1.0 / 64 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : ABR-15000 kbps / 0.60
x265 [info]: tools: rd=2 psy-rd=0.30 rdoq=2 psy-rdoq=1.00 early-skip signhide
x265 [info]: tools: tmvp b-intra fast-intra strong-intra-smoothing deblock sao
x265 [info]: tools: stats-write
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\Ying\FF\Xman-4K_3840x2160_50sec_15M_H265_veryslow_2pass.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : X-MEN__DAYS_OF_FUTURE_PAST.Title800
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 50.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : (26)01:17:27:726
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (libx265) ([35][0][0][0] / 0x0023), yuv420p, 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 15000 kb/s, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30
 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.57.100 libx265
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.57.100 libvo_aacenc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (libvo_aacenc))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1502 fps=2.6 q=-0.0 Lsize=  100652kB time=00:00:50.01 bitrate=16485.9kbits/s dup=75 drop=0
video:99814kB audio:782kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:1kB muxing overhead: 0.054657%
x265 [info]: frame I:     11, Avg QP:13.26  kb/s: 59293.48
x265 [info]: frame P:    443, Avg QP:15.21  kb/s: 33977.10
x265 [info]: frame B:   1048, Avg QP:18.35  kb/s: 8420.64
x265 [info]: global :   1502, Avg QP:17.39  kb/s: 16330.84
x265 [info]: Weighted P-Frames: Y:4.5% UV:4.5%
x265 [info]: Weighted B-Frames: Y:1.9% UV:1.6%
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 23.8% 11.9% 14.8% 22.9% 17.8% 7.0% 0.0% 0.0% 1.8%

C:\Ying\FF>C:\Ying\FF\ffmpeg.exe -y -i C:\Ying\FF\Xman-4K_50sec_3840x2160.mp4 -preset veryslow -x265-params pass=2 -vcodec hevc -b:v 15M -acodec libvo
_aacenc -b:a 128K C:\Ying\FF\Xman-4K_3840x2160_50sec_15M_H265_veryslow_2pass.mp4
ffmpeg version N-74286-ge5774f2 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontco
nfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-l
ibfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-am
rwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-lib
twolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --en
able-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 30.100 / 54. 30.100
  libavcodec     56. 57.100 / 56. 57.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 32.100 /  5. 32.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Ying\FF\Xman-4K_50sec_3840x2160.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : X-MEN__DAYS_OF_FUTURE_PAST.Title800
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:50.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11067 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 50.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : (26)01:17:27:726
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 11492 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (de
fault)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 1.7
x265 [info]: build info [Windows][GCC 4.9.2][64 bit] 8bpp
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-6 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 32 threads
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 8 / wpp(34 rows)
x265 [error]: statistics are damaged at line 1495, parser out=1
[libx265 @ 0000000001e97d00] Cannot open libx265 encoder.
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\Ying\FF\Xman-4K_3840x2160_50sec_15M_H265_veryslow_2pass.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : X-MEN__DAYS_OF_FUTURE_PAST.Title800
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 50.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : (26)01:17:27:726
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 0:0, 30 fps (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.57.100 libx265
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac, 0 channels, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.57.100 libvo_aacenc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (libvo_aacenc))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

MediaInfo:

```html
General
Complete name                            : E:\4K\2ndRound\Xman-4K_50sec_3840x2160.mp4.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 66.0 MiB
Duration                                 : 50s 6ms
Overall bit rate                         : 11.1 Mbps
Movie name                               : X-MEN__DAYS_OF_FUTURE_PAST.Title800
Writing application                      : Lavf56.40.101

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L5.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 47s 567ms
Bit rate                                 : 11.5 Mbps
Width                                    : 3 840 pixels
Height                                   : 2 160 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.046
Stream size                              : 65.2 MiB (99%)

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 50s 6ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 781 KiB (1%)

Menu #1
ID                                       : 3
Codec ID                                 : text
Duration                                 : 50s 0ms
Language                                 : English

Menu #2
00:00:00.000                             : (26)01:17:27:726

​
```

Comment: The 2nd pass has this: `x265 [error]: statistics are damaged at line 1495, parser out=1`. I'd say, upgrade first to recent build.

Comment: @Mulvya, You are so smart! Yes, downloaded the latest FFmpeg version, and the problem is solved!